# crontab not executing script

Tags: cron, startup

I'm trying to launch a script located at /Documents/scripts/startup.sh that only contains the command `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` on startup. I added it to crontab by executing `crontab -e` and appending `@reboot /Documents/scripts/startup.sh` to the crontab. however on launch, checking /mnt shows that the drive was not mounted. I also verified that crontab was running by doing `sudo service cron status` and it is running. I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Edit: Adding log of service

```
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop CRON[995]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop CRON[1036]: (root) CMD (sudo mount dev/sda1 /mnt)
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop CRON[1035]: (jovan) CMD (/home/jovan/Documents/scripts/startup.sh)
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop CRON[996]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop CRON[996]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user jovan
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop sudo[1037]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mount dev/sda1 /mnt
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop sudo[1037]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop sudo[1037]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop CRON[995]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
May 02 11:20:24 jovan-desktop CRON[995]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Thank you.

Comment: Look up how to redirect cron output to another file so you can read the error message.

Comment: Welcome! Shouldn't be `/home/user/Documents/scripts/startup.sh`?

Comment: Thank you! I tried that too but unfortunately it didnt work either.

Comment: Did you change the `user` in my example for your real user? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: yes of course haha. I added a log to the post if that helps.

Comment: I can understand your frustration, however the MTA refers to the Mail transfer agent. it has nothing to do with the problem I am experiencing, nor is it really an error. I fixed by appending >/dev/null 2>&1 after my command in the crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(root) CMD (sudo mount dev/sda1 /mnt)
```

This is missing the leading `/` in `/dev/sda1`

```
(jovan) CMD (/home/jovan/Documents/scripts/startup.sh)
```

This runs with your (jovan) identity. You can't expect it to somehow guess your password to authenticate to `sudo`, can you ;) I would say putting `sudo` anywhere in a non-interactive script is wrong.

Note that for mounting filesystems at boot time, there is [the `/etc/fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/fstab.5.html) file. You just add your filesystem there and the startup scripts (or `systemd`) will mount it, unless your mark it `noauto`.

And last, I would certainly recommend you to install the mail transport agent (even if only one that delivers mail on your machine), in that case you'd get the error message in your mailbox.

Comment: I actually noticed that too, but my script reads "sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt" Should I add an additional "/"?. Also is there a way to modify the script so it can perform the same task without sudo? Sorry for the noobish questions I am fairly new to linux.

Comment: That's not from your script, that is another entry from the crontab (possibly, an earlier attempt?). Your script `startup.sh` runs without root privileges, you can't have it mount drives. You could however add it into root's crontab.

Comment: IMHO the least convoluted way to solve this would be to edit the root's crontab, add the missing slash, drop `startup.sh` altogether and be done with it.

Comment: Oh, and did you try to put `/mnt` in `/etc/fstab`? That's the file just for this purpose.

Comment: That fixed it! I cleared the user crontab and added the mount command directly into the root crontab without using the script. Thank you for the help!